# typescript- filter array of objects based on another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, for-loop

I have an array of objects like given below

```
  readonly allItems = [
    {
      id: 0,
      title: "Item 0",
      belongsTo: 'admin'
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Item 1",
      belongsTo: 'user'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "Item 2",
      belongsTo: 'all'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "Item 3",
      belongsTo: 'user'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      title: "Item 4",
      belongsTo: 'all'
    }
  ];
```

And I have an array of numbers like given below

```
let selItems = [0,2,4];
```

What I'm trying to do is, filter the `allItems` array based on `selItems` array
For doing that, I wrote the following code, which is obviously wrong.

```
  for(let i=0; i< this.allItems.length; i++){
      if(selItems.includes(this.allItems[i].id)){
        tempMenu.push(this.allItems[i]);
      }
      console.log(tempMenu);
    }
```

I'm getting the following as output

```
[{
      id: 0,
      title: "Item 0",
      belongsTo: 'admin'
}]
```

The result I'm expecting is like this:

```
  [
    {
      id: 0,
      title: "Item 0",
      belongsTo: 'admin'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "Item 2",
      belongsTo: 'all'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      title: "Item 4",
      belongsTo: 'all'
    }
  ]
```

Can anyone show me the right way to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might use `.map` instead:

```js
const allItems = [{
    id: 0,
    title: "Item 0",
    belongsTo: 'admin'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Item 1",
    belongsTo: 'user'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Item 2",
    belongsTo: 'all'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Item 3",
    belongsTo: 'user'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: "Item 4",
    belongsTo: 'all'
  }
];
const selItems = [0, 2, 4];

const output = selItems.map(num => allItems.find(({ id }) => id === num));
console.log(output);
```

To reduce computational complexity to `O(N)` instead of `O(N^2)`, you can transform it into an object indexed by `id` first:

```js
const allItems = [{
    id: 0,
    title: "Item 0",
    belongsTo: 'admin'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Item 1",
    belongsTo: 'user'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Item 2",
    belongsTo: 'all'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Item 3",
    belongsTo: 'user'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: "Item 4",
    belongsTo: 'all'
  }
];
const selItems = [0, 2, 4];

const allItemsById = allItems.reduce((a, item) => {
  a[item.id] = item;
  return a;
}, {});

const output = selItems.map(num => allItemsById[num]);
console.log(output);
```

Or with `filter`:

```js
const allItems = [{
    id: 0,
    title: "Item 0",
    belongsTo: 'admin'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Item 1",
    belongsTo: 'user'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Item 2",
    belongsTo: 'all'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Item 3",
    belongsTo: 'user'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: "Item 4",
    belongsTo: 'all'
  }
];
const selItemsSet = new Set([0, 2, 4]);

const output = allItems.filter(({ id }) => selItemsSet.has(id));
console.log(output);
```